# Python - How to extract multiple url in .csv element

Tags: python, csv

My data in .csv is like

{'ID': 'NN00', 'URL': 'http://...', 'Pic': "['http://...', 'http://...',... ]"}

I want to extract the url in 'Pic' , how can I suppose to do?

I try this:

```
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
      for j,ele in enumerate(row['Pic']):
         print(ele)
```

and I got the character individually

How can I do?

---

Following is my code:

```
with open('WB_INTENTION_with_pic.csv',encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as csvfile:
fieldnames = ['ID', 'URL', 'Pic']
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for i, row in enumerate(reader):
    pic = json.loads(row['Pic'])
    for p in pic:
        print(p)
```

And some row['Pic'] is empty "[]" , some is "['http://...', 'http://...',... ]"

[My sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8lCp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if your csv is in correct format. Otherwise csvreader will not work properly. I have constructed a sample csv based on your example as-

```
#sample csv
ID,URL,Pic
NN00,http://...,['http://abc.xyz', 'http://pqr.lmn', 'http://456.123']
NN01,http://...,['http://wdc.xyz', 'http://23fpwedr.lmn', 'http://423156.123']
NN02,http://...,['http://zazbxcec.xy32z', 'http://pq24f23r.lmn', http://45dw6.123']
```

Now just read csv line by line -

```
with open('urls.csv', 'r+') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        for url in row['Pic'][1:-2].split(','):
            print(url.replace("'",""))

=>output
http://abc.xyz
http://pqr.lmn
http://456.123
http://wdc.xyz
http://23fpwedr.lmn
http://423156.123
http://zazbxcec.xy32z
http://pq24f23r.lmn
http://45dw6.123
```

Comment: But I want to extract the individual url in row['Pic']

Comment: Made appropriate changes. Please check now.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the Pic element is't a list

```
'Pic': "['http://...', 'http://...',... ]"
```

It's a string. You need to convert it to JSON first.

```
for i, row in enumerate(reader):
    pic = json.loads(row['Pic'])
    for p in pic:
       ....
```

Comment: it turns out json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1) Something wrong?

Comment: post a real sample please

Comment: an actual sample of your data and it should be edited into your question

Comment: Your edit does not contain an actual sample of your data